# UX impact and considerations for robot that can change skin face color, face features, and do so, while it speaks, on demand (on the fly, move on

Tags: user-expectation, customer-experience, new-experience, ro

What would be the value, of a robot, teacher, that has a face, that could change skin color and head characteristics (features, protrusions). Even color combinations, and moment (control,

Would it's value exceed that if humans?

- As the robot, taught, it could make (or spike), different associations, in the user (the student, (the learner)), allowing the user to engage in different thought patterns, affected by head configurations, style (and, resulting multiplicity considerations, (things that they had, might inspire, as being to heart) or other).
- The advantage of this robot, making it, superior, to humans, would be that it could change face, provoking different (:-) and new, novel) linkages, between thought styles.

This affects the student.

The student is able to make (new,

New stuff.

- The robot can change, what the different associations are (but also display, the reactions, of different face counterparts (on demand (on the fly, (in, palace
- The robot can, improvise, conversations (dialogues, with head in place

Thank you for your considerations.

The only obstacle I would see to producing such a robot, would be producer (and, consumer? party??

gealousy.

I hope I am wrong. A good robot, should, be (thought inspiring, (and not gealousy provoking

Maybe, that is just the reaction it would cause in me.

Well, thank you for your considerations.

I post on this groups, because while I don't doubt, good engineers, would be able to implement the face color, changes on demand, and change mechanics for facial features, ...

I want to know what you think about this, from a UX perspective.

Thanks.

Thank you.

The best part could also be that the interaction between the different faces is NON HARMFUL, because, they are the same face (so, as long as the face was in cross-interaction face making mode, and, not, towards mode, ... you, could think that.

(this could have an alleviating effect, which, could be reflected in reality, or... well, this would be the most alleviating,

A face could also have a towardsing, mode

Alas, what you can make with a face is much and many

But I want a good, robot.

How to get inside (or, to grips with...

This

:-

-)

;

-)

-~

;/D)

Comment: This would probably not take away the fact that humans would interact in the same way, regardless of what the robot did. But, the robot, could, counter, interact.

Comment: Also, some robots, could be more action provoking.

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of my post, is (but, as I write this, I, am... able, to, see, different